# Is there a way to gift Battlefield 3?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3, origin

Is there a way to purchase Battlefield 3 and/or Battlefield 3 Premium online and be able to give that copy to a friend? (buy it online without binding it to your own account)

For instance, just get ahold of the game's [product key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_key) and give that to them so that they can activate the game on their Origin account?

There doesn't appear to be any option to do so via [Origin](http://store.origin.com/).

Comment: PS: Who exactly *likes* Origin? Anyone?

Comment: The interface is semi-pleasant. Other than that, Steam >> Origin. Sorry EA.

Comment: Origin allowed you to install games in a separate directory before Steam did, which may have pushed Steam to add the feature, which in turn pleases me.

Comment: I'll take Steam's interface over Origin's garbage any day of the week. That said, I don't see why this question should be considered off topic -- we're not here to make value judgements on publishers or digital distribution platforms, and he's asking a valid question.

Comment: I think the only good thing about Origin is that it starts fast. Steam takes way to long to start up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can purchase the game from another retailer and simply give the key to the recipient. There are many sites. Here are a couple Battlefield 3 Premium Edition links:

- [GamersGate.com](http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-BF3PE/battlefield-3-premium-edition) (this site has a 'gift' option which allows you to gift a game to a fellow user on GamersGate, or email it to someone)
- [Amazon.com](http://amzn.com/B0098QPPL6)
- [GreenManGaming.com](http://www.greenmangaming.com/s/ca/en/pc/games/shooter/battlefield-3-premium-edition-na/)
- [GameFly.com](http://www.gamefly.com/Download-Battlefield-3-Premium-Edition/5004583/)

With Premium Edition, usually you will get 2 keys: one for Limited Edition (with karkand) and one for Premium.

Comment: - Greenmangaming.com was buggy and clicking the "Buy" button associated with Battlefield 3 Premium Edition did nothing but reload the page.
- Amazon.com doesn't allow Canadians to purchase digital downloads (even though it gets downloaded via Origin).
I'll add some more alternatives to your list. Thanks for the suggestions, though!

Comment: Are these available to players outside the US? if not, then this answer would be too localized.

Comment: AFAIK most of them are also available in Germany, too, my copy of BF3 is from Amazon.com, so I don't think it's too localized.

Comment: @Lemmings19 Amazon.com can be made to work with a Canadian credit card for digital download.

Comment: @Ampersand The other sites appeared to be readily available for use in Canada without any messing around. I purchased from GamersGate without a hitch.

Comment: @Lemmings19 Yeah, it's a pain. However the deals are too good sometimes. Just a few weeks ago premium edition was $30 iirc.

Answer (score -1):

It has been suggested by EA Support staff that people can log in with their friends' accounts to purchase the items.

I've done this successfully for my younger brothers so I know it works.

Comment: It would not surprise me that this is a method the support staff at EA have suggested, and no doubt it does work. But it just sounds like a horrible idea from a security standpoint for both parties involved. If the purchaser isn't careful, his/her credit card info could be saved to the friend's account. And the friend? He/She needs to change their password after the transaction, because their account security has been *compromised*.

I'd suggest either handing your friend the cash (or a pre-paid visa), and telling him to buy the game.