# How can I gift a game via Origin?

Tags: origin

I would like to buy a friend of mine a copy of the new SimCity game before it is released next month on Origin, however I cannot find a way to purchase a game for a friend on Origin like you can on Steam.

Is it possible to gift a game on Origin and if so how can I achieve this?

If it isn't possible to gift a game on Origin, are there any alternate methods to achieve a similar outcome?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to name that one a duplicate for this one.

Comment: Problem is, without an upvoted answer to this one, there's no way to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, there is no gift feature (like in Steam) from Origin itself.

You can buy Origin keys from internet sites and give the key to your friend.

Example sites (Taken from Ampersand's answer on a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105974/is-there-a-way-to-gift-battlefield-3)):

- [GamersGate.com](http://www.gamersgate.com/) (this site has a 'gift' option which allows you to gift a game to a fellow user on GamersGate, or email it to someone)
- [GreenManGaming.com](http://www.greenmangaming.com)
- [GameFly.com](http://www.gamefly.com/)

Comment: Funny thing is, my google gives me only german sites. Just try to google "Buy Origin Key Online" or something similar.

Comment: I fixed the links now.

Comment: EA is really dumb for not allowing a gifting option